# Allow undelete vote on posts deleted for spam

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, spam, vote-to-undelete

As [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214434/please-undelete-an-answer-to-my-question) showed me, when you look at a answer that was deleted as spam, you can no longer see it (which is just fine with me) and you have to click on another link to see it's review history.  BUT there is no way to cast an undelete vote on mis-deleted items (example in the linked question), so how about we still have an undelete link in the deleted post for those circumstances.

Realizing from the comments and answers that flagging may be the better way to go, I created [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214443/all-deleted-posts-need-a-flag-link) to keep the flag link on those deleted posts.

Comment: There is already a feature request / bug report about spam and offensive posts not having `flag` and `undelete` links, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ahh, too much caffeine in my system this morning.  I'll go look for that.

Comment: The post is deleted by Community, which is a moderator.  You cannot vote to undelete a post deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Servy, valid point.

Comment: Minor typo: "another like" should be "another link", I believe

Comment: @Teeg, got it, thanks.

Comment: @Servy That's only if it actually get deleted by the spam flags. If a post is otherwise deleted by 10k users, it's still hidden even if there was a *single* spam flag.

Comment: @animuson Yep, I'm not saying this functionality shouldn't be changed.  More that I wasn't sure *how* it behaved in the situation you're describing; I was curious if the undelete option might have been there in such a case.  That's why I posted just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it really was mis-deleted, then chances are that spam flag was also invalid and needs to be cleared, which can only be done by a moderator. So I think just flagging it for their attention is the best option there. Upon clearing spam/offensive flags, a post is automatically undeleted anyways.

So a better option is a flag link. We don't want to encourage potential undeletion of spam.

Comment: OK, [new request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214443/all-deleted-posts-need-a-flag-link).