# All deleted posts need a 'flag' link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, deleted-answers

Answers that are deleted for being spam or offensive do not have a `flag` link on them.  There will be times when the poster (or maybe someone else) will want to flag for reasons of appeal or questions or whatever.

**All deleted posts should still have a flag link to flag a moderator.**

Comment: Good idea. Also - somewhat related, but different http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212242/allow-me-to-close-vote-deleted-questions .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the "hide offensive content on deleted posts from 10k users" feature was implemented, these got dropped by error.

Fixed now and with you in the next build.